# CSRF Middleware - change csrf_token output (from xHTML to HTML)

Tags: html, django, csrf

I've a problem with django csrf middleware...
when I use the template tag csrf_token I get this output:

```
<div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='6bda3605af31dd8595d2a67d0dda827b' /></div>
```

but I want this output (HTML not xHTML:

```
<div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='6bda3605af31dd8595d2a67d0dda827b'></div>
```

I tryed to see the code in django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware but with no success :(

So, how can I change the output fo csrf_token tag?

tanks

Comment: Please note that CSRFMiddleware is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.4. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2-alpha-1/#csrf-protection for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go and edit django.template.defaulttags.py: At line 48 there is the output of the tag, and you may change it as you wish.

Please note that this is a development feature, and as such, subject to change - updating Django will likely remove your change!.
Also, please take the time to go [look for a ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/query) about this particular problem: the solution I proposed will likely fix your problem, but I think that an “official” fix would be a lot nicer.

Comment: yeah!!! I didn't found this :'(
however I'll create a my_csrf_token so when I'll update django it will be easy to fix any problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my fix to the problem.

```
{% with csrf_token as csrf_token_clean %}{{ csrf_token_clean }}{% endwith %}
```

In your template, this will return only the token key, so you can write your own valid HTML input tag, like this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{% with csrf_token as csrf_token_clean %}{{ csrf_token_clean }}{% endwith %}" >
```

Source: http://www.phptodjango.com/2010/07/django-csrftoken-template-tag-fix.html

Answer (score 3):

The solution is actually very simple:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
```

There is no point in `{% with %}` construct.